# Firestore credentials problem: Firebase app [default] already exists

Tags: java, firebase, gradle, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm building a simple program in JavaFX for uploading .xls files to my firebase/firestore project. Everytime I try to run the program and click on a button to init my uploader class, it fails with an error message:

> FirebaseApp name [DEFAULT] already exists!

After searching for a long time, I have yet to find something useful. I've tried OAuth2 tokens (created a service account in Google Cloud, got the JSON file), environment variables (won't detect), pretty much everything in docs.

```
  FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("<path>.json");
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://<project>.firebaseio.com/")
        .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options); <----This line won't compile for some reason..
Firebase app =FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options); <--------- This will compile
```

I'm using Gradle for my building tool. This is what I've got so far and it seems to build nicely without problems. Am I missing any dependencies?

```
 plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
    id 'application'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()
}

dependencies {

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile "org.apache.poi:poi:3.17"
    compile "org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.17"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.2.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.9.0'


}
javafx {
    version = '12'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

mainClassName = 'app.Main'
apply plugin: 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `firebase-admin` alongside other Firebase Android libraries like `firebase-auth` and `firebase-firestore`. You should either use the Admin SDK or the Android SDK, but never both.

Coming to the exact error message, it's an indication that `initializeApp()` is getting called multiple times in your app. It's trying to initialize the `[DEFAULT]`, when one already exists.